# Как отлаживать Typescript в Webstorm?

Tags: typescript, webstorm

Не могу разобраться.
Создал `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "system",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outFile": "./index.js",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

И простой код на ts:

```
var list: number[] = [10, 20, 30];
var colors: string[] = ["red", "green", "blue"];
console.log(list[0]);
console.log(colors[1]);
```

И что дальше делать понятия не имею. Подскажите, как сие чудо запустить, когда нажимаю `Run`, он мне выдает подменю `Edit Configuration`. В котором я не пойму что настраивать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

включите typescript компилятор (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Typescript, `Enable TypeScript compiler` and `Use tsconfig.json`), после того, как Ваш код скомпилируется,в контекстном меню скомпилированного файла (`index.js`) выберите Debug. Ну и точки останова, конечно, надо поставить в ts файле